# Alignment within a Table Row

Tags: html, css, ruby-on-rails

I know this is probably stupid simple, but I'm not a CSS guy.  I've got three text objects within a single table row that I need to space left, center, and right.  Perferrably, I'd like to specify their exact position within the tr.  Here's my code:

```
  <tr>
  <td class="stext">
  NAME <%= @cms484.person_name %>
  TITLE <%= @cms484.person_title %>
  EMPLOYER <%= @cms484.person_emp %>
  </td>
  </tr>
```

My attempts to adjust the CSS by creating divs within the table row broke the table.

Comment: if they are bare text then you can't select them with CSS..they need to be in separate elements.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OKay, if you are really really unsure about what you are doing and as far as I understand, you need to do something like this:

```
<tr>
  <td class="stext">
    <table class="equal-three-col">
      <tr>
        <td>
          NAME <%= @cms484.person_name %>
        </td>
        <td>
          TITLE <%= @cms484.person_title %>
        </td>
        <td>
          EMPLOYER <%= @cms484.person_emp %> 
        </td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </td>
</tr>
```

And in your CSS:

```
.equal-three-col td {width: 33%;}
```

Comment: Perfect, thank you.  Saved me a lot of fumbling around.  Never considered making a table within a table.  Thanks alot

Answer (score 0):

```
<tr>
<td class="stext">
NAME <%= @cms484.person_name %>
TITLE <%= @cms484.person_title %>
EMPLOYER <%= @cms484.person_emp %>
</td>
</tr>
```

to

```
<tr>
<td class="stext">
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>NAME <%= @cms484.person_name %></td>
    <td>TITLE <%= @cms484.person_title %></td>
    <td>EMPLOYER <%= @cms484.person_emp %></td>
 </tr>
</table>
</td>
</tr>
```

Hope this help you. Using css you can set it too but for that please post the relevant css you used for `.stext`, depends on `td` width specified if any.

Answer (score 0):

Why not put them in their own column

```
` <tr>
  <td class="col1">
  NAME <%= @cms484.person_name %>
</td><td class="col2">
  TITLE <%= @cms484.person_title %>
</td><td class="col3">
  EMPLOYER <%= @cms484.person_emp %>
  </td>
  </tr>`
```

Then you could specifiy the text-align property in css:

```
.col1 {
    text-align:left;
}
.col2 {
    text-align:center;
}
.col3 {
    text-align:right;
}
```